# Can a creature swap places with another willing creature on their turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

I understand that a creature can move through the space of another willing creature on their turn, but may not stop there. **Is it possible to swap places with an adjacent and willing creature and, if so, does this count against the movement for the swapped creature's next turn?**

To illustrate:

```
A = PC1 - it is this creature's turn,
B = PC2,
C = Enemy Creature,
X = Occupied Space

XXXXXX      XXXXXX
 ABC X  ->   BAC X
XXXXXX      XXXXXX
```

Is the above movement legal, and does it count towards B's movement on its next turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, with a readied action.

If B readied an action to move away when A entered his space–a perceivable condition–they would effectively swap places on A's initiative. This seems to be allowed by RAW, as neither player ends any movement in another's square, if the movements are resolved simultaneously. If movement is not resolved simultaneously, it should still be possible, with some fancy footwork, and a different trigger for B's Ready–that A begins to move.

Both options cost B's action on his own turn, however.

Comment: I agree that this is the right answer, but it is very expensive in terms of the action economy. As a house rule, I would allow any two willing adjacent creatures to swap places provided each uses their reaction and the swap happens during the turn of one of the creatures. The rule would apply to both PCs and NPCs/ monsters

Answer (score 8):

## No, you cannot move when it's not your turn

Page 190 states (emphasis mine):

> **On your turn**, you can move a distance up to your speed…[y]ou can break up your movement **on your turn**…

But nothing about moving on someone else's turn.

The ready action (page 193) is an exception to this:

> First, youdecide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then…you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

The trigger could be "when they move into my space, I move." But that costs you your action to ready, and your reaction to actually move.

You could use one attack to shove them 5' back, but that takes up one of your attacks, and not all classes get extra attacks.

There are class features (Maneuveríng Attack) that allow your allies to move as their reaction during your turn, and spells (*telekinesis*) that allow you to move creatures on your turn.

But there is nothing in the PH that I can find that allows you to swap places with someone.

Comment: You say you cannot move when it's not your turn, but then you talk about using a Ready action which *does* allow you to move when it's not your turn.

Comment: @LegendaryDude how's the edit?

Answer (score 6):

### Maybe, Yes, But…

It is going to cost an attack and probably all your movement. It also might not be allowed by the GM, depending on how they read "moving grappled creatures").

First, A grapples B, using an Attack Action (using up one attack, if A has Extra Attacks). If B is willing then this succeeds without any roll required.

Second, A moves to B's square, moving B at the same time to the square where A was. A's movement is halved (moving while grappling) and halved again (moving through occupied squares) so they probably only have 7 feet of movement (or one square, if using a grid).

Your GM might rule against the second task, with, "If B is in front of A, then A's movement must end with B still in front of A."

If it is allowed then the creatures to the left of where A was will get attacks of opportunity against A. Since B is being forcibly moved then they will not trigger any attacks against them

Answer (score -5):

Im having a hard time finding it but there is a rule that a willing creature can be moved by another creature without using their movement.  It is reference in provoking an attack of opportunity "You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction."

It is considered a free action; per your example if A moved B to get to C to heal, his movement through B is like if someone stood behind you and pulled you back as they stepped forward. As long as B doesn't resist A's movement will replace B's position.

Comment: Do you have actual rules citation to back this up?  The bit about Opportunity Attacks not being provoked when something moves you without using your movement is in reference to being shoved, moved by a spell effect such as *Thunderwave*, or being grappled and moved by your enemy.